# Get the width of a div when width set by css class

Tags: jquery

This JS script gives me an alertbox saying;

```
jQuery.UI.version = 1.0.2  ---   Box Width: undefined
```

How can I select the `#resizable`?

```
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <style>
  #resizable { width: 200px; height: 150px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red;}

  </style>

      <script>
        $(function () {
            var boxWidth = $('#resizable').attr('width');
            alert("jQuery.UI.version = " + jQuery.ui.version + "  ---   Box Width: " + boxWidth);           
        });
  </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="resizable" class=">
        <div id="title">
            <h2>
            The expanding box
            </h2>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As you can see, the problem is not with selecting the element (that works fine), it's about accessing the information (width) properly. Just wanted to point this out explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here you don't have a attribute of `width`:

```
<div id="resizable" class=">
```

this will surely crash and set to `undefined`, `var boxWidth = $('#resizable').attr('width');`

There are two ways getting the width of an element like:

By the `.width()` way:

```
$('#resizable').width();
```

and by `.css()` way:

```
$('#resizable').css('width');
```

Answer (score 3):

your selector `$('#resizable').attr('width');` search for attribute `width` in resizable which does not exists

i think you are asking for `width()`

try this

```
 var boxWidth = $('#resizable').width(); //this gives you the width of resizable div
```

**updated seeing comment**

your code reads the attribute width of div `<div id="resizable" class="asd">` ..but see , there is no attribute called width in this div so it fails... doc to read more about [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

your code will work if you add width in div like `<div id="resizable" class="asd" width="30px">`...this will give you  `30px` as alert...

Comment: Thanks! How come this works and my dont? I got my code from the jQuery site.

Comment: @Lautaro: Your `div` element don't have a `width` attribute. Only `id` and `class`. Even if you would set a custom `width` attribute, it would just give you the value you set, not the actual width of the element.

Comment: @Lautaro i have explained it in my answer.....anyways your code reads the attribute width of div `<div id="resizable" class="asd">` ..but see theres is no attributes called width in this div... your code will work if you add width in div like `<div id="resizable" class="asd" width="30px">`...this will give you alert as 30px

Answer (score 1):

try this bit:

```
$('#resizable').width();
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a width attribute on that div, are you trying to get the width property of the div? try

```
$("#resizable").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('#resizable').width()); will you give 200

alert($('#resizable').css('width')); and this will you give 200px
```

[div width](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/YnLk8/)

Answer (score 0):

With Pure JavaScript you can do this in following way:

```
document.getElementById('resizable').clientWidth;
```