# getting text block length with css (preferred) or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to know the actual length of div below after filling with text? with css (preferred) or javascript.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:steelblue;
  font-family: roboto;
}
```

```html
<div>what is my length?</div><br/>
<div>what is my length then????</div>
```

Comment: Length as in width in pixels, or length as in number of characters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680785/getting-width-of-a-div-element,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471767/get-div-width-and-height-in-javascript,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945877/get-the-width-of-a-div-when-width-set-by-css-class, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, you can use `offsetWidth`. You also have `offsetHeight` for the height.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a").offsetWidth);
console.log(document.getElementById("b").offsetWidth);
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">what is my length?</div><br/>
<div id="b">what is my length then????</div>
```